# consumer.poll(100) is not returning any record

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

I have Kafka `Producer` and `Consumer` with transaction semantics. I am facing an issue while running Kafka `Consumer` with `isolation.level= read_commited`. Kafka `Consumer` is not able to consume records as poll is not returning any record because last stable offset is coming as 0.

This is the debug log of Kafka `Consumer` where last stable offset is coming as 0:

> (error=NONE, highWaterMark=50, lastStableOffset = 0, logStartOffset => 0, abortedTransactions = [], recordsSizeInBytes=0)

How this last stable offset gets updated?? I am committing transaction from `Producer` Side, and one when i am running `Consumer` without Transactional semantics it is consuming records well.

Comment: Are you using `sendOffsetsToTransaction()`?

Comment: Yes below is the snippet of code :-

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    
                   Future<RecordMetadata> futureResult = producer
      .send(new ProducerRecord<String, String>(record.getTopic(), record.getPayload()));
    /*
     
    RecordMetadata ack = futureResult.get();
    
    String topic =ack.topic();
     int p = ack.partition();
     TopicPartition tp = new TopicPartition(topic, p);
    long offset = ack.offset();
     OffsetAndMetadata om = new OffsetAndMetadata(offset);
     hm.put(tp, om);
    
   }
   producer.sendOffsetsToTransaction(hm, "cg4");
   producer.commitTransaction();